# Unable to display different views in same page using angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript

here i am trying to display the various views in single page. that is with in the same page i created 3 different divs and each view is have different content .here i can able to navigate to 2  views but for getting the 3rd views when i am pressing the button it is displaying 2nd and 3 rd view together

below is my code:

```
<div class="container">


    <div *ngIf="showData">
         <p>This is page 1</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="testOne()">Page 1
         </button>
           <br>
           <br>
         <button (click)="page3()" >click here for page 3</button>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div *ngIf="!showData">
        <p> this is page 2</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="back()">Back to page1</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!showData">
       <p>Page 3</p>
    </div>  

</div>  

 showData = true;


  testOne(){
    this.showData = false;
  }

  back(){
    this.showData = true;
  }

  page3(){
    this.showData = false;
  }
```

below is my stack blitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyw1cs

Comment: page 2 and 3 show together because you tell them to

Comment: but if try to add another also starting ngif condition it is not working

Comment: you need multiple variables if you want to do it via ngifs, or just use angular's routing

Comment: i dont want to use angular routing so by multiple variables  using how can we do

Comment: by having 1 variable per div you want to open...

Comment: i Found the solution and working

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following stackblitz url I have updated the same stackblitz that you have attached.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1vsy7
The code can also further be optimized its just to give you a rough idea how to do it with three seperate variables.

Comment: but if u press one button for various times then it is enabling and disabling

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly is your requirement based on the code I have provided in the given stackblitz.